# SleekXMPP: Getting presence['muc']['jid'] to message handler for each message

Tags: python, xmpp, chat

I'm connecting to an XMPP server using a SleekXMPP script. My problem is `msg['from']` and `presence['muc']['jid']` have completely different results.

`msg['from']` returns: `channelname@channels.example.com/nick`

`msg['mucnick']` returns: `nick`

`presence['muc']['jid']` returns: `username@example.com`

Note that "username" and "nick" are two unique values of the same user in this case. I need the "username" value recorded for each message in the message handler.

Is there a way to get the same output as `presence['muc']['jid']` in the message stanza handler?

Answer (score 1):

So I solved this by saving presence login data to a dict.

```
def muc_online(self, presence):
    handle = str(presence['muc']['jid']).split('@')[0]
    nick = str(presence['muc']['nick'])
    userdata = {nick : handle}
```

Then I just match the nick in the message stanza with the dict created from the presence stanza.